# Pairing or Connecting input and button elements with angular

Tags: html, angular, web-frontend, angular-tour-of-heroes

I was following the tutorial [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial). While [adding a new hero](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-a-new-hero) they say

> You can use an  element paired with an add button.
> Insert the following into the HeroesComponent template, after the heading:

```
<div>
  <label for="new-hero">Hero name: </label>
  <input id="new-hero" #heroName />

  <!-- (click) passes input value to add() and then clears the input -->
  <button type="button" class="add-button" (click)="add(heroName.value); heroName.value=''">
    Add hero
  </button>
</div>
```

Here I don't understand what is `#heroName` inside in input element (what is it called) and how does it help in pairing that input element with the button element.

Basically, what is that `#<keyword>` syntax within that input element. I know that it is not the `id` as that is already declared.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, it's a reference to the input. You can find more details here:

https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables

> Template variables help you use data from one part of a template in
> another part of the template. Use template variables to perform tasks
> such as respond to user input or finely tune your application's forms.

In the tutorial context, it's a reference to the input element. It helps to pair it with a button to be able to access it's value, without having to actually define a variable in the component.ts and trying to update the template directly. This help you "skip" a step, and actually have direct access to that value.

Template reference variables can become very handy in certain cases and are commonly used for example in angular material ( to call a function for a component )

```
<mat-menu #menuComponent ...></mat-menu>
<button (click)="menuComponent.close()"></button>
```

In the above example, you bind the menuComponent variable to "mat-menu" component, in which case you can access all the variables, public methods of such. In that case we can call "close" method from the mat-menu component.

Let me know if this is still unclear and I can try to give you more examples and explanation